# Why didn't Anna get promoted?

Tags: character, analysis, the-art-of-self-defense

Why is Anna not promoted to Black belt in Karate even though she excelled in the art and could outperform every student in the class? But instead, a guy with a lesser talent got promoted to Black belt.

Is it because she has some feminine energy in her or is it because she's a woman?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sensei (Leslie) is misogynistic throughout the movie. He casually insults Anna simply because she is female. He claims women have different (lesser) abilities, they can not be as strong as men, etc. He passes her over for promotion to black belt because of his sexism.

(IIRC, he even says "she will never become a black belt", and that karate is for men but not women.)

Comment: To highlight this, there is a tradition of sexism in several martial arts. An example is that in Judo women used to have to use a special black belt with a white stripe (meaning that it was not a "complete" black belt); the international federation did make wearing it optative some decades ago but in Japan it was mandatory until recently: https://theolympians.co/2017/03/22/keiko-fukuda-and-the-white-stripe-in-the-black-belt-a-symbol-of-gender-discrimination-in-judo-fades-to-black/